# How to create nested Repeater/Group Fields in Prismic Slices

Tags: reactjs, slice, prismic.io

I have to create nested Repeater/Group Fields in Prismic Slices in order to achieve the data for nested rows and columns table to be displayed in order to get a table preview like give [Carbon Collective Table](https://www.carboncollective.co/climate-index)